# MSBuild /p:AdditionalLibPaths is not working as expected

Tags: msbuild

**Scenario:**

I'm trying to Compile/Build a .Net c# application using MSBuild in Jenkins. I want the MSBuild to look at a given location for all the Dependent DLLs and use them instead of the ones referenced in the project.

**Project file has :** (which should be ignored and replaced with the path given in the command line below)

```
<Reference Include="T">
  <HintPath>..\..\SharedLib\Unstable\T.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

[image]

**Desired behavior:**
Override the project level setting (**C:\Testing\SharedLib\Unstable**) and use the dlls that are in **C:\Testing\SharedLib\Stable** when compiled from Jenkins MSBuild using the command line .

**My Attempt:**

```
msbuild C:\Testing\TestMSBuild\TestMSBuild.sln /p:AdditionalLibPaths="C:\Testing\SharedLib\Stable"
```

Console Output Log:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are several similar questions from the past which are not answered. I hope to get an answer and make it useful for people out there.

Comment: This worked for me

CMD> msbuild C:\Testing\TestMSBuild\TestMSBuild.sln /p:ReferencePath="C:\Testing\SharedLib\Stable"